# Xcode 4.4 doesn't recognize git

Tags: git, xcode4, osx-mountain-lion

I did a clean install of Mountain Lion yesterday, and I transferred all my files over manually. One of the folders contains my Xcode projects, some of which had git repositories in them. I installed Xcode 4.4, but when I opened a git project, it doesn't recognize any changes anymore. That is, I can make a change and try to commit it, but it simply says "No files". The little M or A or whatever in the Project Navigator doesn't show either. I have the Command Line Tools installed. `git`

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you checked that the .git directory is intact in these folders? From the command line, is git able to see the repository fine?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention: the git folder is present in the project's folder. I'm not sure how I would check if git could see the repository, not too familiar with all of this...

Comment: git is able to see the repository fine. I `cd`ed to my app folder in Terminal, then did `git log` and it shows me the latest commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling Xcode worked. No idea still what was wrong, but all I care about is that it is working now.

Answer (score 5):

Open the Organizer window (Cmd-Shift-2) and click the Repositories tab. Does it show up there? Does it indicate a problem? Also, try closing the project, clicking the Organizer's Projects tab, selecting your project and deleting it from the organizer (your project won't be deleted, only Xcode's "awareness" of it until you open it again).

Comment: It shows up, but it says "No revision". Deleting and reopening the project has no effect either...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem while working with Git and Xcode. My files were marked as both *deleted* and *unstaged* when I called `git status`, independently on how many times I had called `git add` before. My project folder was synchronized using SugarSync same time. After I excluded the `.git` folder from SugarSync and did `git reset` on affected files, everything worked correctly again.

So check if any synchronization service (iCloud, Dropbox etc.) is not disturbing Git’s territory.